# Parse info from Text File - Powershell

Tags: powershell, parsing

Beginner here, I am working on a error log file and library, the current step I am on is to pull specific information from a txt file.

The code I have currently is...

```
$StatusErr = "Type 1","Type 2"

for ($i=0; $i -lt $StatusErr.length; $i++) {
  get-content C:\blah\Logs\StatusErrors.TXT | 
    select-string $StatusErr[$i] |
    add-content C:\blah\Logs\StatusErrorsresult.txt
}
```

while it is working, I need it to display as

```
Type-1-Description  
2-Description  
Type-1-Description  
2-Description  
Type-1-Description  
2-Description
```

etc.

it is currently displaying as

```
Type 1 = Type-1-Description  
Type 1 = Type-1-Description  
Type 1 = Type-1-Description  
Type 2 = 2-Description  
Type 2 = 2-Description  
Type 2 = 2-Description
```

I am unsure how to change the arrangement and remove unneeded spaces and the = sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to search for *both* patterns in a *single* [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) call in order to get matching lines in order.

  - While the `-Pattern` parameter does accept an *array* of patterns, in this case a single *regex* will do.
- You need to use a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) pattern in order to capture and output only *part* of the lines that match.

```bash
$StatusErrRegex = '(?<=Type [12]\s*=\s*)[^ ]+'

get-content C:\blah\Logs\StatusErrors.TXT | 
  select-string $StatusErrRegex |
  foreach-object { $_.Matches.Value } |
  set-content C:\blah\Logs\StatusErrorsresult.txt
```

<sup>Note that I've replaced `add-content` with `set-content`, as I'm assuming you don't want to append to a preexisting file. `set-content` writes *all* objects it receives via the pipeline to the output file.</sup>

`Select-String` outputs [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) instances whose `.Matches` property provides access to the part of the line that was matched.

For an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/HsiKVg/2).

Additional notes:

- `Select-String`, like PowerShell in general, is case-*insensitive* by default; add the 
  `-CaseSensitive` switch, if needed.
- `(?<=...)` is a (positive) lookbehind assertion, whose matching text doesn't became part of what the regex captures.
- `\s*` matches *zero or more* whitespace characters; `\s+` would match *one or more*.
- `[^ ]+` matches one or more (`+`) characters that are *not* `^` spaces ( ), and thereby captures the run of non-space characters to the right of the `=` sign.
- To match any of multiple words at the start of the pattern, use a regex *alternation* (`|`), e.g. `'(?<=(type|data) [12]\s*=\s*)[^ ]+'`